# Use Instance method instead of Database field while accessing in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have database field called name. And i have used user.name in my application. Now I have something like salutation which i wanted to append with the name. So what i basically want is when i am accessing name via user.name it should fetch the value from instance method rather then database field.

```
def name_with_salutation
 "#{salutation} #{name}"
end
```

So when i am accessing name via user.name it should respond with user.name_with_salutation. I have tried alias_method but it shows stack level too deep because name is getting used in name_with_salutation so it got stuck in infinite process.

I am trying this because i do not want to replace name with name_with_salutation throughout the application. This should not apply when i am assigning values user.name = "abc".

Please let me know, How this will be done.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To overwrite an original Model method, you can write a method with same name, and then use `read_attribute(:attr)` to represent the original attribute value.

Given `name` attribute exist, to overwrite `#name`:

```
def name
  "#{salutation} #{read_attribute(:name)}"
end
```

Comment: Do you think its a good idea because when we are saving the user record it validates salutation_with_name instead of name. And there is no way to fetch the original name(have to use this read_attribute(:name))

Comment: @nishant610, I don't think that is a good idea. The new #name method helps you manipulate the output but is not intended to replace the attribute. When validating, respect the raw input of whatever. For your second question, yes it is, and isn't that what you want to do? If you don't want to change behavior of original #name, you need to write a new method with different name instead of overwriting it.

Comment: Basically i have to show name_with_salutation to user at view end and i cannot update the database field and user.name present at lots of places, So i don't want to change user.name with user.name_with_salutation at each place and after using read_attribute when i am saving the record it validates salutation which i don't want. I want salutation only for display purpose.